# How to hide a row if a field is empty?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to hide an entire row in the case of a field is empty:

example
[image]

in the event that some field is empty, I want to hide all the entire row, either from javascript or from jquery. I tried some tricks, but nothing hides me the entire row. Is that possible?

```
            <table class="pmpro_affiliate_report" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>                
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Sub-ID</th>             
                <th>Name</th>       
                <th>Miembro</th>                        
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Estado</th>             
                <th>Order Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                $sqlQuery = "SELECT a.code, o.affiliate_subid as subid, a.name, u.user_login, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(o.timestamp) as timestamp, o.total FROM $wpdb->pmpro_membership_orders o LEFT JOIN $wpdb->pmpro_affiliates a ON o.affiliate_id = a.id LEFT JOIN $wpdb->users u ON o.user_id = u.ID WHERE o.affiliate_id <> '' ";
                if($report != "all")
                    $sqlQuery .= " AND a.id = '" . esc_sql($report) . "' ";
                $affiliate_orders = $wpdb->get_results($sqlQuery);
                if(empty($affiliate_orders))
                {
                ?>
                    <tr><td colspan="6" class="pmpro_pad20">                    
                        <p>No affiliate signups have been tracked yet.</p>
                    </td></tr>
                <?php
                }
                else
                {
                    global $pmpro_currency_symbol;
                    // if($affiliate_orders->user_login != ''){
                    foreach($affiliate_orders as $order)
                    {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $order->code;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $order->subid;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo stripslashes($order->name);?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $order->user_login;  if($order->user_login == '') {unset($order->user_login);}?></td>
                        <td><?php echo date(get_option("date_format"), $order->timestamp);?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $used_statuses;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $pmpro_currency_symbol . $order->total;?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: If you want to do this in JavaScript, why are you showing PHP code and tagging the question with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't need js for this, just add an if statement before echoing the tr

```
foreach($affiliate_orders as $order)
{ if( !empty(.......) ){
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may just be better off iterating through the order values in your `foreach`, only returning the table row if all fields have a value. Otherwise you'll be outputting needless HTML with the only purpose of hiding it.

That being said, if you were set on using JS/Jquery, you could do something like this...

```
$('table tr').each(function() {  //For each table row

    //If there's an empty field
    if ($(this).find('td:empty').length) {

        //Remove the row
        $(this).remove(); 

    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p5m4jc72/1/)

Your question was vague on whether or not it was a specific field, or *any* field. In the case of a specific field, you should really just do that in your PHP or SQL.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass check on sql query not to select a value whereever there is empty field

```
SELECT a.code, 
 o.affiliate_subid as subid, 
 a.name, 
 u.user_login, 
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(o.timestamp) as timestamp, 
 o.total FROM $wpdb->pmpro_membership_orders o 
 LEFT JOIN $wpdb->pmpro_affiliates a 
 ON o.affiliate_id = a.id 
 LEFT JOIN $wpdb->users u 
 ON o.user_id = u.ID WHERE 
 o.affiliate_id <> '',
 o.affiliate_subid <> '', 
 a.name <> '', 
 u.user_login <> '',
 o.timestamp <> '',
 o.total <> ''
```

Answer (score -2):

[UPDATE]
yes with JQuery **classList.add('invisible');**

i think you'll need JQuery bootstrap to do this
check http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

im using this on my project and it's working

```
function changeVisibility(){
    $secret.classList.add("invisible");
}
```